# What is the nth term of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Hi can you help me determine the $n^\text{th}$ term of the sequence $1, \frac{1}{2}, 3, \frac{1}{4}, 5, \frac{1}{6}, 7...$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sequence can be given by the formula $$a_n = n^{(-1)^{n+1}}$$

Alternatively, it may also be defined by

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
n, & n \equiv 1 \pmod{2} \\ \frac{1}{n} & n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 4):

For $n = 2k - 1$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have that $a_n = n$.

For $n = 2k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have that $a_n = n^{-1}$.

You should try and generalize from this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence.

We have $a_{2k+1}=(2k+1)^1$ and $a_{2k}=(2k)^{-1}$.

We want to write $a_n=n^{m_n}$, where $m_n$ is such that $m_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if } n=2k+1 \\
-1 & \text{if } n=2k
\end{matrix}\right.$.

Such parameter can be chosen as $m_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Hence, $$a_n=n^{(-1)^{n+1}}.$$